# React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: Params

Tags: reactjs, dependencies

Once I run the below code, I get the following error:

```
  Line 19:5:  React Hook useEffect has missing dependencies: 'departureDate', 'from', and 'to'. Either include them or remove the dependency array  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
```

This is my Code

```
import axios from 'axios';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import {Link, useParams} from 'react-router-dom'

function DisplayFlights() {
  const {from,to,departureDate} = useParams()
  const [flightData,setFlightData] = useState([])
  const [isLoading,setLoading]=useState(true)




  useEffect(()=>{
    axios.get('http://localhost:8081/flightnews/flights?from='+from+'&to='+to
    +'&departureDate='+departureDate).then(res=>{
      setFlightData(res.data);
      setLoading(false);
    })
  },[])
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Flights:</h2>
      <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
            <th>Airlines</th>
            <th>Departure City</th>
            <th>Arrival City</th>
            <th>Departure Date and Time</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {!isLoading?flightData.map(flight=><RowCreator item={flight}/>):""}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  );
}

function RowCreator(props){
  var flight = props.item;

  return <tr>
    <td>{flight.operatingAirlines}</td>
    <td>{flight.departureCity}</td>
    <td>{flight.arrivalCity}</td>
    <td>{flight.estimatedDepartureTime}</td>
    <td><Link to={'/passengerDetails/'+flight.id}>Select</Link></td>
  </tr>
}
export default DisplayFlights;
```

I tried to call useParams inside the callBack like that I could have all of the dependencies but I can't do that because is not a function .

Thanks for helping me

Answer (score 0):

Since your effect "depends on" the variables `from`, `to` and `departureDate`, you must put them in the dependency array:

```
useEffect(()=>{
  // consider adding this so that the UI shows if new data is being fetched.
  // setLoading(true);
  axios.get('http://localhost:8081/flightnews/flights?from='+from+'&to='+to
    +'&departureDate='+departureDate).then(res=>{
    setFlightData(res.data);
    setLoading(false);
  })
},[from, to, departureDate])
```

Now, your effect will run anytime those variables change, which is what you need.

---

See [useEffect reference](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect)

Answer (score -1):

In this case I would suggest you to wrap the api call in usecallback hook to avoid infinite loop. Your code would then look like this

```
const fetchNews=useCallback((from, to, departureDate)=>{
  axios.get('http://localhost:8081/flightnews/flights?from='+from+'&to='+to
+'&departureDate='+departureDate).then(res=>{
  setFlightData(res.data);
  setLoading(false);
})
},[])

useEffect(()=>{
  fetchNews(from, to, departureDate)
},[fetchNews,from, to, departureDate])
```

Comment: You need `fetchNews` in your deps array now

Comment: Yes, missed that out